# Insert Ignore into not working is giving error in php

Tags: php, psql

So, I have a php script in which I am fetching data from a data source and saving it into a array and the inserting the array values into my psql server using php.

The problem is I don't want any duplicates in my database as I will keep updating my tables. So I looked up and found IGNORE INTO to avoide duplicates but php throws an error.

Moreover as I don't have any primary key in my table, is it possible to still achieve that.

My error code:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Exception: Error attempting to query: PDOException: SQLSTATE[42601]: Syntax error: 7 ERROR:  syntax error at or near "IGNORE"
```

My php script to insert data in psql server

```
$psql = $stm->pdo_prepared("Insert IGNORE INTO student(student_id,student_email,student_message,student_marks)VALUES".implode(',',$arry1());
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: A table with no PK is just a bad start... Constraints of unicity on primary key would do the trick

Comment: `INSERT IGNORE` is meaningless without a primary key or unique constraint.

Comment: If you don't tell your db what a duplicate is, how is it supposed to prevent inserting them?  Also, if you're going to say that you're getting an error, always include the error in your question.

Comment: Ok, I'll make a pk in my database. but i am confused, while I was running my script the php throws an syntax error on IGNORE. Do you guys think that is because if no pk in my table

Comment: I didn't read all of your post I guess, but yeah, you need a primary key. I figured student_id was it.

Comment: Is `pdo_prepared()` a custom function?  It's not a native function, nor a function used by any of the frameworks I'm aware of.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Please post the error, but I believe you're likely getting a syntax error.  You need the values in braces and some spaces that could be causing a syntax error as well.

```
$psql = $stm->pdo_prepared("INSERT IGNORE INTO student (student_id,student_email,student_message,student_marks) VALUES (".implode(',',$arry1()) . ")";
```

I would also suggest doing the following.  You can see more information here:

http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT IGNORE INTO student (student_id, student_email, student_message, student_marks) VALUES (:student_id, :student_email, :student_message, :student_marks)");
$stmt->bindParam(':student_id', $student_id);
$stmt->bindParam(':student_email', $student_email);
$stmt->bindParam(':student_message', $student_message);
$stmt->bindParam(':student_marks', $student_marks);
```

Comment: I updated my answer with some suggestions. You definitely have some incorrect syntax in your SQL statement. Some spaces are incorrect and you're missing braces. Please see if one of my solutions works and let me know.

Comment: And also be sure to make the student_id primary, otherwise IGNORE won't work, as others have mentioned.

Comment: oh ok, thank you, I will run the script after making the pk and I'll comment again.

Comment: Any idea why the error message says the error is near `IGNORE`?

Comment: I think that sometimes comes up when it goes back to see its last valid part of the statement. Did what I posted work?